# Shared abstract implementation of a generic interface method: "The method does not override method from its superclass"

Tags: java

I have an interface:

```
public interface Validator<T extends Document>
{
    boolean isValid( T  document ) throws DocumentValidationException;
}
```

and I have an abstract class which implements this abstact method:

```
    public abstract class SharedValidator<T extends Document> implements Validator
{
    @Override
    public boolean isValid( final T document ) throws DocumentValidationException
    {
        if ( null == document )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Finally, I have two subclasses which extend the abstract class:

```
public class ValidatorA extends SharedValidator<DocumentA>  {
}

public class ValidatorB extends SharedValidator<DocumentB>  {
}
```

where `DocumentA` and `DocumentB` are subclasses of an interface, `Document`.

(Forgive the trivial implementation in the abstract method. It's a simplified case for the purposes of sharing online).

I can't get this to work.

It says in my abstract class that "the method does not override method from its superclass".

Yes it does!

What is the theory behind why this does not work?

My goal here is to have a common abstract implementation in my abstract class, and use my subclasses to provide the correct type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're using a raw type for `Validator`.

```
public abstract class SharedValidator<T extends Document> implements Validator
```

Should be changed to:

```
public abstract class SharedValidator<T extends Document> implements Validator<T>
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Your simple answer helps me to see how the "chaining" that I require works, and what I was missing.

Comment: @8bitjunkie Happy to help.  If you'd like, I can edit my answer and explain why it fails with a raw type.

Comment: I would find that very interesting if you could. I would like to understand more about generic types and bounded types. I find the official literature very dry!